# Is it possible to find an algorithm which gives coordinates of the basis elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, free-modules

Suppose $R$ to be a ring with unity, and we have a module homomorphism $f: A \to B$, where $A,B$ are $R$-modules.

Suppose the image $f(A)$ is free $R$-module of rank $2$ with $R$-basis $\{u,v\}$. We know exactly the values $u,v$.

Suppose we know the value of $f(a_0)$ for some fixed $a_0 \in A$.

Take an arbitrary $a \in A$, then we have $f(a)=\alpha u+\beta v$ for some scalars $\alpha, \beta \in R$.

Let me add more information. The homomorphism $f$ is series map, and we can compute $f(a)$ for any $a \in A$ by putting $a$ in the series representing $f$ but in that case $f(a)$ will have inaccuracy.

> Is it possible to derive an algorithm which starts with $f(a_0)$ and at the end find the coordinates $\alpha, \beta$ so that we can find exact or at least more-accurate (degree of precision) value of $f(a)$ ?

---

The importance of the question is that-if we can find the coordinates $(\alpha, \beta)$, then we can find the value of $f(a)$ for arbitrary point $a \in A$ with better degree of precision.

Comment: Knowing $f(a_0)$ is not enough information on its own to determine $f(a)$ for all $a \in A$. What are the permissible steps in this "algorithm"? Are we able to know $f(a)$ for other elements $a \in A$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, yes, $f(a)$ can be computed for many $a \in A$ approximately, because the map $f$ is itself a series. So may be we get an algorithm which improves the accuracy. I want to apply the basis in the algorithm. Any idea please

Comment: What do you mean by "improves the accuracy"?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, I mean degree of precision

Comment: If you want to set up an "algorithm", as you keep referring to it, then you need to be precise about what exactly we know at the outset. For example, do we specifically know what the elements $u$ and $v$ are, or do we merely know that such $u,v$ exist?

Comment: "Degree of precision" is equally imprecise

Comment: @BenGrossmann, yes we know what are $u$ and $v$ ?

Comment: If we know specifically what the vectors $u$ and $v$ are, then surely we can make use of the coordinate maps $\pi_u,\pi_v : f(A) \to R$ given by $\pi_u(\alpha u + \beta v) = \alpha$ and $\pi_v(\alpha u + \beta v) = \beta$

Comment: @BenGrossmann, How exactly one can know what are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ? can you show an example please ?

Comment: If you have an example in mind, perhaps **you** should share that. My example would simply be a linear map $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$, but I presumably this is not the kind of situation you're interested in

Comment: @BenGrossmann, yes you are right. I have other but similar example in mind. I am focusing your example at first. Suppose $f(A)$ is free $\mathbb R$-module of rank $2$. So let $f(A)$ has basis $\{u=(1,0), v=(0,1)\}$. Say, we want to evaluate $f(a)$ for $a \in A$, where assume $f=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$. Then in terms of $u,v$, we have $f(a)=\alpha (1,0)+\beta(0,1)$ for some unknown $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$. On the other hand, we can find approximate value $f(a)$ by putting $x=a$ in the series, which will have error. Here is my question- if $\alpha, \beta$ can be (continued)

Comment: @BenGrossmann, (continued) obtained by some algorithm so that we have better correct value of $f(a)$.

Comment: First of all, I'm not sure how $f = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$ can be interpreted so that $f$ is a module homomorphism. Second, if you have $f(a) = \alpha(1,0) + \beta(0,1) = (\alpha,\beta)$, then why can you not simply read the first coordinate of this result to get $\alpha$ and the second coordinate to get $\beta$?

Comment: Regarding the point of "accuracy" and "precision", the point here is that most modules don't come equipped with some kind of notion of "distance" between vectors. Are we given that $B$ is equipped with a metric or a norm? If not, then there is no meaningful interpretation of the phrase "improve the accuracy" in this context. The only "improvement" to be made is from $0\%$ (the wrong answer) to $100\%$ (the right answer).

Comment: @BenGrossmann, well, I should tell the problem. Consider $p$-adic field $\mathbb Q_p$ with its ring of integeers $\mathbb Z_p$. The $p$-adic logarithm $\log_p: M=1+p \mathbb Z_p \to N=p \mathbb Z_p$ is homomorphism, where $M,N$ are $\mathbb Z_p$-module. Note $\log_p(1+x)=\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n}$. Now I know the basis of $\log_p(M)$, say $\{u,v\}$.  My question is to compute $\log_p(a)$ for arbitrary $a \in M=1+p \mathbb Z_p$. Ofcourse $M,N$ has $p$-adic metric which measure length